# Drag and drop Recyclerview with checkbox triggering previous position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have the following code for handling drag and drop option for RecyclerView.

```
class TodoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var adapter: ToDoItemAdapter
    lateinit var touchHelper: ItemTouchHelper
    var list: ToDoList? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        .....

        rv_item_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        .....


        touchHelper =
                ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0) {
                    override fun onMove(
                        rv: RecyclerView,
                        dragged: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                    ): Boolean {
                        val dragged_item_pos = dragged.adapterPosition
                        val target_item_pos = target.adapterPosition
                        Collections.swap(list.items, dragged_item_pos, target_item_pos)
                        adapter.notifyItemMoved(dragged_item_pos, target_item_pos)
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onSwiped(p0: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
                        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }
                })

        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_item_list)

    }


    class ToDoItemAdapter(val context: Context, val activity: TodoActivity) :

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, pos: Int) {
            holder.cb_completed.setOnClickListener {
               .....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without dragging any item I tried to check the checkbox which is working fine. Now the problem is after dragging items if I check the item it is triggering the checkbox which was there earlier.

Eg:

```
I have Item 1, Item 2, Item 3.
I dragged the Item 3 to Item 1 position.
Now the order is Item 3, Item 1, Item 2
If I check Item 3(Position 0), Its checking Item 2(Position 2). Because currently Item 2 has the position of previous Item 3 position.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the answer myself. So I am adding this answer. 

Using position for updating the checked status is wrong. Because the position of the item will vary while moving the item. To handle that I am using a unique id for finding the exact object.
First, I am setting the unique id as the tag for the checkbox.

```
holder.cb_completed.tag = activity.list!!.items[pos].id
```

Inside Onclick listener finding the object which matches the unique id. Once we found, I am updating the checkbox value

```
holder.cb_completed.setOnClickListener {
    activity.list!!.items.forEach { it ->
        if(it.id == holder.cb_completed.tag.toString().toLong()){
            it.isCompleted = holder.cb_completed.isChecked
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it help to others.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got 50 rep so can't leave a comment but I had a similar issue and it was because I wasnt updating the list that i pass to the adapter

```
fun updateAdapterList(newList: MutableList<Object>) {
    adapterList.clear()
    adapterList.addAll(newList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

In your case just use `notifyItemMoved(dragged_item_pos, target_item_pos)` and pass in the positions required.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried to do that inside onMove method. But If I do that, I am not able to drag an item for more that one position. Because of onMove method getting called for every position change.